# Processing.exe Doesn't Respond to System() (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, processing

I exported my Processing project, which renders as P3D, successfully. The .exe file works, even from the command line. I need to run this executable from a c++ program. When I call

```
system("Project_name.exe");
```

on it, it doesn't open up the file. I checked the path by opening other types of files like .txt successfully. I also tried it with system("start Project_name.exe")and it gives the same input.

Is it because its not reading java with the app properly? The java folder is also in the same directory. I am using VS 13 Pro. Please help!

Note: I understand system calls are not the best approach. I also used CreateProcess but was not successful. I think the file is opened but the frame and contents doesn't display.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System command works fine in case of interactive applications, starting notepad works fine.
Please ensure your application and dependencies are picked up from the right path, You may try to set path environment variable within c++ application.
If you are able to run this application from command line, you may write a batch file to invoke your application and invoke this batch file from c++ application using system command